# Signing into Hangouts as Resource and/or mirroring user & resource calendar?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working on a Proof of Concept. I would like to have be the homepage be g.co/hangouts in a conference room where it shows all the meeting in that room.

I think to do this I would either have to sign into google with the resource's account info OR have a user account named "UserRoom1" and whenever someone, using their own account schedules the resource "Room1," "UserRoom1" is invited to that meeting.

any way this can be accomplished? I want to make this as invisible/user-proof as possible so asking users to remember to simply invite "UserRoom1" to all of the meetings in "Room1" is significantly less ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the exact same thing, and I think it is only possible if you buy one of Google's [Chromebox for Meetings](https://www.google.com/work/chrome/devices/for-meetings/index.html) products, which costs a minimum $1K, and then requires a $250/yr subscription after the first year. [This page](https://support.google.com/chromeboxformeetings/answer/3341435) shows how to associate a Chromebox for Meetings with a calendar, which seems to be the functionality we are missing. Ultimately I think you have to do the "User as Resource" setup, so "UserRoom1" shows up in the list as a user (rather than a resource). Slightly janky but it mostly gets the job done.

We also have a few common hangouts that I have bookmarks set up for on the conference room computer's Chrome bookmarks bar, so we're not totally bound to the meeting invite hangouts.